# ValueError: Mix type of y not allowed

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, bayesian-networks

I have lottery data and I am trying to prediction with that. But I'm stuck with reshaping the data.

My data is structured like that:

```
0,Week,Date,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6
1,1140,15/08/2018,3,10,15,18,25,43
2,1139,11/08/2018,9,15,16,21,32,33
3,1139,11/08/2018,9,15,16,21,32,33
```

My Python code:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('son.csv')

# fit a Naive Bayes model to the data
model = GaussianNB()
y = dataset.values[:,9].reshape(1143,-1143)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(dataset, y, test_size=0.2)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(model)
# make predictions
expected = X_test
predicted = model.predict(y_test)
# summarize the fit of the model
print(metrics.classification_report(expected, predicted))
print(metrics.confusion_matrix(expected, predicted))
```

However, I am getting this error:

> ValueError: Mix type of y not allowed, got types
>   {'multiclass-multioutput', 'binary'} error.

How I can fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please proofread and properly format your questions. Thanks!

Comment: Show data from your `y`

Answer (score 2):

The following error 
`ValueError: Mix type of y not allowed`
ocurs due to more than one type of value being present in the target variable( in your case multiclass and binary). Please make sure that the target dataset(y) contains same type of data for each sample.